# After loading website automatically goes to a specific section

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I add an custom html to my website. After implement this custom element my website automatically goes that section. But I want it will stay in header section after load. How can I do that? Should I apply any JavaScript or Css? If I need that please notify me.
This is my custom html that I added:

```
<div class='container'>
    <b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'>
    <div class='mega-flex'>
     <b:section class='cooking-area' id='cooking-area' maxwidgets='5' name='Category Labels' showaddelement='no'>
       <b:widget id='Image16' locked='true' title='Veg Plate Recipe' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'></b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>150</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='link'>/search/label/Prisma%20Theory</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='caption'>Green Chilly, Rice and more</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
         <b:includable id='content'>
                  <div class='widget-content'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-img'>
                      <b:if cond='data:link'>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'/>
                        </a>
                        </b:if>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-title'>
                      <h2>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <data:title/>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </b:if>
                  <b:if cond='data:caption'>
                  <span class='image-caption'><data:caption/></span>
                </b:if>
                </b:includable>
       </b:widget>
       <b:widget id='Image26' locked='true' title='Bread Toast Recipe' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'></b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>150</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='link'>/search/label/Prisma%20Theory</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='caption'>Honey, Nuts, cookies etc</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
         <b:includable id='content'>
                  <div class='widget-content'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-img'>
                      <b:if cond='data:link'>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'/>
                        </a>
                         </b:if>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-title'>
                      <h2>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <data:title/>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </b:if>
                   <b:if cond='data:caption'>
                  <span class='image-caption'><data:caption/></span>
                </b:if>
                </b:includable>
       </b:widget>
       <b:widget id='Image36' locked='true' title='Strawberry Shake' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'></b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>150</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='link'>/search/label/Prisma%20Theory</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='caption'>Condence Milk, Fruits etc.</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
         <b:includable id='content'>
                  <div class='widget-content'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-img'>
                      <b:if cond='data:link'>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'/>
                        </a>
                       </b:if>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-title'>
                      <h2>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <data:title/>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </b:if>
                   <b:if cond='data:caption'>
                  <span class='image-caption'><data:caption/></span>
                </b:if>
                </b:includable>
       </b:widget>
       <b:widget id='Image66' locked='true' title='Eggs Pasta Recipe' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'></b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>150</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='link'>/search/label/Prisma%20Theory</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='caption'>Eggs, Cauliflower, Bread etc</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
         <b:includable id='content'>
                  <div class='widget-content'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-img'>
                      <b:if cond='data:link'>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'/>
                        </a>
                         </b:if>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-title'>
                      <h2>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <data:title/>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </b:if>
                   <b:if cond='data:caption'>
                  <span class='image-caption'><data:caption/></span>
                </b:if>
                </b:includable>
       </b:widget>   
       <b:widget id='Image106' locked='true' title='Dora Cakes Recipe' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'></b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>150</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='link'>/search/label/Prisma%20Theory</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='caption'>Pan, Choco, Breads cutter etc.</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
         <b:includable id='content'>
                  <div class='widget-content'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-img'>
                      <b:if cond='data:link'>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'/>
                        </a>
                       </b:if>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-title'>
                      <h2>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <data:title/>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </b:if>
                   <b:if cond='data:caption'>
                  <span class='image-caption'><data:caption/></span>
                </b:if>
                </b:includable>
       </b:widget>
       <b:widget id='Image116' locked='true' title='Cookies Coffee Recipe' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'></b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>150</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>100</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='link'>/search/label/Prisma%20Theory</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='caption'>Water, Beans Choco etc</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
         <b:includable id='content'>
                  <div class='widget-content'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-img'>
                      <b:if cond='data:link'>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'/>
                        </a>
                        </b:if>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-title'>
                      <h2>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <data:title/>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </b:if>
                   <b:if cond='data:caption'>
                  <span class='image-caption'><data:caption/></span>
                </b:if>
                </b:includable>
       </b:widget>
       <b:widget id='Image126' locked='true' title='Brown Bread Recipe' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'></b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>140</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>150</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>335</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='link'>/search/label/Prisma%20Theory</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='caption'>Eggs, Brwon Breads, Cream etc</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
         <b:includable id='content'>
                  <div class='widget-content'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-img'>
                      <b:if cond='data:link'>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'/>
                        </a>
                        </b:if>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                    <div class='cooking-area-title'>
                      <h2>
                        <a expr:href='data:link'>
                          <data:title/>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </b:if>
                   <b:if cond='data:caption'>
                  <span class='image-caption'><data:caption/></span>
                </b:if>
                </b:includable>
       </b:widget>
     </b:section>
      <b:section class='dom-flex' id='dom-flex' maxwidgets='5' name='Author Image' showaddelement='yes'>
        <b:widget id='HTML2' locked='false' title='' type='HTML' visible='true'>
          <b:widget-settings>
            <b:widget-setting name='content'>&lt;div class=&#39;main-domain&#39;&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Buy Domain with&lt;span class=&quot;bkash&quot;&gt; Bkash&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;
        &lt;form class=&quot;input&quot; id=&quot;input&quot;&gt;
            &lt;input autocomplete=&quot;off&quot; autofocus=&quot;&quot; id=&quot;name&quot; name=&quot;name&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; /&gt;
            &lt;button&gt;Check&lt;/button&gt;
        &lt;/form&gt;
        &lt;div class=&quot;results&quot; id=&quot;results&quot;&gt;
            &lt;a class=&quot;domain&quot; href=&quot;#&quot; id=&quot;domain&quot;&gt;helloworld.com&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a class=&quot;domain&quot; href=&quot;#&quot; id=&quot;domain&quot;&gt;helloworld.com&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;div class=&quot;push&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;</b:widget-setting>
          </b:widget-settings>
          <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:include name='widget-title'/>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <data:content/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>
      </div>
        <div class='clearfix'/>
        </b:if>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (!document.location.hash){
    document.location.hash = 'first-load';
}
```

```css
p {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    background-color: green;
}

p:target {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a nisi nisi, non dapibus augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In massa urna, auctor et lobortis a, tempus sit amet diam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam at erat eget est commodo sagittis non sed lorem. Sed ac sapien nisl. Vestibulum condimentum nunc a nisl consequat sodales. Pellentesque fringilla gravida ipsum, ut tristique nisi consequat nec. Donec et ante erat. Nunc molestie imperdiet purus, et vehicula purus commodo eget. Curabitur lorem lacus, tempus a ultricies at, consequat nec nisi. Nunc ac nibh congue risus adipiscing mollis non ac quam. Sed non purus vel turpis interdum sagittis. Integer laoreet lobortis nisi vel hendrerit. Etiam vel nisl in sem vehicula mattis.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a nisi nisi, non dapibus augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In massa urna, auctor et lobortis a, tempus sit amet diam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam at erat eget est commodo sagittis non sed lorem. Sed ac sapien nisl. Vestibulum condimentum nunc a nisl consequat sodales. Pellentesque fringilla gravida ipsum, ut tristique nisi consequat nec. Donec et ante erat. Nunc molestie imperdiet purus, et vehicula purus commodo eget. Curabitur lorem lacus, tempus a ultricies at, consequat nec nisi. Nunc ac nibh congue risus adipiscing mollis non ac quam. Sed non purus vel turpis interdum sagittis. Integer laoreet lobortis nisi vel hendrerit. Etiam vel nisl in sem vehicula mattis.</p>
<p id="first-load">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a nisi nisi, non dapibus augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In massa urna, auctor et lobortis a, tempus sit amet diam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam at erat eget est commodo sagittis non sed lorem. Sed ac sapien nisl. Vestibulum condimentum nunc a nisl consequat sodales. Pellentesque fringilla gravida ipsum, ut tristique nisi consequat nec. Donec et ante erat. Nunc molestie imperdiet purus, et vehicula purus commodo eget. Curabitur lorem lacus, tempus a ultricies at, consequat nec nisi. Nunc ac nibh congue risus adipiscing mollis non ac quam. Sed non purus vel turpis interdum sagittis. Integer laoreet lobortis nisi vel hendrerit. Etiam vel nisl in sem vehicula mattis.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a nisi nisi, non dapibus augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In massa urna, auctor et lobortis a, tempus sit amet diam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam at erat eget est commodo sagittis non sed lorem. Sed ac sapien nisl. Vestibulum condimentum nunc a nisl consequat sodales. Pellentesque fringilla gravida ipsum, ut tristique nisi consequat nec. Donec et ante erat. Nunc molestie imperdiet purus, et vehicula purus commodo eget. Curabitur lorem lacus, tempus a ultricies at, consequat nec nisi. Nunc ac nibh congue risus adipiscing mollis non ac quam. Sed non purus vel turpis interdum sagittis. Integer laoreet lobortis nisi vel hendrerit. Etiam vel nisl in sem vehicula mattis.</p>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).